# How to move custom marker to front

Tags: google-maps

How to move custom marker to front on google map?

I found moveToTop function for GoogleMaps Flash API, but no one for "standard" API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the zIndex for a new custom marker when you create it, with the [zIndexProcess](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarkerOptions.zIndexProcess) property on the [GMarkerOptions](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarkerOptions) constructor parameter.